# PHP Regex: Get info between groups of HTML tags?

Tags: html, regex, parsing, html-parsing

I have been programming a word-unscrambler. I need to parse the information between a group of tags and another, and put all matches into an array. The beginning tag is:

```
<tr> <td></td><td><li>
```

and the ending tag is:

```
</li></td> </tr>
```

I know some regular expressions, but I am unfamiliar with PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<tr> <td><\/td><td><li>(.*)<\/li><\/td> <\/tr>
```

Test is here: http://rubular.com/regexes/13241

Answer (score 0):

PHP can cope with both [PERL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) and [POSIX](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.regex.php) regexes, so you'll need to use the function for the flavour that you know. I believe that the code posted by @Gazler should work in either case, though it will need to be surrounded by `/`s, and quoted:

`$reg = '/<tr> <td><\/td><td><li>(.*)<\/li><\/td> <\/tr>/';`

There's a PHP PERL regex based test site here: http://j-r.camenisch.net/regex/